# How can I break only long word which is coming under the overflow

Tags: html, css

I am trying to break-word but when I am using this code

```
word-wrap: break-word;
-ms-word-wrap: break-word;
-webkit-word-wrap: break-word;

word-break: break-all;
-ms-word-break: break-all;
-webkit-word-break: break-all;

-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
```

it breaks all the words in line but I need only break the word which is long, others will come in two lines, for more explain I sure fiddle link.

the result still is coming

> STATIONERY BU
>
> NDLES

But I required

> STATIONERY
>
> BUNDLES

link below
https://jsfiddle.net/Alvee/Ljuzrjp4/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, by changing the little bit design wise

```
<div class="centralize">
    <div class="flexIcon">
       <img src="images/services/web-development.png" />
    </div>
    <span>Development</span>
</div>

.centralize {
      display:   flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be sufficient to remove the

`word-break: break-all;
-ms-word-break: break-all;
-webkit-word-break: break-all;`

section. According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp), `word-break: break-all` states that lines may break between any two letters, which is exactly what you are trying to avoid.

Comment: if i removed this lines, then long word is not break

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you are trying to achieve then... You would like to break a line when the word at the margin is too long, but also break the word into multiple lines if it's too long?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden span to calculate the width of span text and adjust the font size.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fvamrav1/3/)

```js
var hiddenSpan = $("#calculatewidth");
$(".flex-item").each(function(i) {
  var divWidth = $(this).find("span").width();  
  var text = $(this).find("span");  
  hiddenSpan.text(text.text());
  var actualWidth = hiddenSpan.width();  
  if(actualWidth > text.width())
  {
    var textVal = text.text();
      var i = textVal.lastIndexOf(" ");
      var firstText = '';
      if(i > 0){                 
       firstText = textVal.substring(0,i);
      }else{
       firstText = text.text();
      }      
      var lastText = textVal.substring(i+1);
      var fontSize = 25;

      hiddenSpan.text(firstText);
      hiddenSpan.css("font-size",fontSize);
     
      while(hiddenSpan.width() > divWidth){
       fontSize -= 1;
        hiddenSpan.css("font-size",fontSize);        
      }
      text.css("font-size",fontSize);      
      if(i>0){
      text.html(textVal.substring(0,i) + "<br/>" + textVal.substring(i+1));
      }     
  }
});
```

```css
.sectionServices{color:white}.sectionServices .container .row{display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap}.sectionServices .container .row>div{margin-left:0 !important;margin-bottom:20px;display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap}.sectionServices .flex-item{width:100%;position:relative;padding:30px 20px 70px;background-color:#2b2b2b}.sectionServices .flex-item .flexIcon{float:left;width:120px;height:90px;background:no-repeat center center}.sectionServices .flex-item .flexIcon.logo-design{background-image:url("../images/services/logo-design.png")}.sectionServices .flex-item .flexIcon.web-development{background-image:url("../images/services/web-development.png")}.sectionServices .flex-item .flexIcon.print-media{background-image:url("../images/services/print-media.png")}.sectionServices .flex-item span{word-wrap:break-word;-ms-word-wrap:break-word;-webkit-word-wrap:break-word;word-break:break-all;-ms-word-break:break-all;-webkit-word-break:break-all;-webkit-hyphens:auto;-moz-hyphens:auto;hyphens:auto;float:left;display:flex;align-items:center;font-size:25px;font-weight:500;text-transform:uppercase;width:calc(100% - 120px);height:90px}.sectionServices .flex-item p{font-size:14px;text-align:center}.sectionServices .flex-item a{background:transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;border:1px solid white;box-shadow:none;position:absolute;bottom:20px;left:calc(50% - 75px)}.sectionServices .flex-item:hover{background-color:#47aa42}.sectionServices .flex-item:hover a{box-shadow:none;color:#2b2b2b;background-color:white}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sectionServices">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col xs12 m6 l4">
        <div class="flex-item">
          <div class="flexIcon" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/parks/themes/recycle/images/services/business-cards.png');">
          </div>
          <span>Business Cards</span>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <p>Our ultimate aim is to identify the most effective and engaging way to bring products, services and core brand objectives into alignment...</p>
          <a href="http://localhost/parks/business-cards" class="waves-effect waves-light btn work">
                                View Work
                            </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col xs12 m6 l4">
        <div class="flex-item">
          <div class="flexIcon" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/parks/themes/recycle/images/services/compliment-slips.png');">
          </div>
          <span>compliment slips</span>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <p>The standard method of printing the typical standard sized comp slip is to lay 3 or 6 up on the press...</p>
          <a href="http://localhost/parks/compliment-slips" class="waves-effect waves-light btn work">
                                View Work
                            </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col xs12 m6 l4">
        <div class="flex-item">
          <div class="flexIcon" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/parks/themes/recycle/images/services/flyers-leaflets.png');">
          </div>
          <span>flyers &amp; leaflets</span>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <p>Whether you need 1m one colour leaflets or a special die-cut shaped flyer printed on glossy board and sealed with gloss UV...</p>
          <a href="http://localhost/parks/flyers-leaflets" class="waves-effect waves-light btn work">
                                View Work
                            </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col xs12 m6 l4">
        <div class="flex-item">
          <div class="flexIcon" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/parks/themes/recycle/images/services/folders.png');">
          </div>
          <span>folders</span>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <p>We have a reputation for producing high quality folders, either bespoke or ‘standard’ shapes, sizes and designs...</p>
          <a href="http://localhost/parks/folders" class="waves-effect waves-light btn work">
                                View Work
                            </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col xs12 m6 l4">
        <div class="flex-item">
          <div class="flexIcon" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/parks/themes/recycle/images/services/letterheads.png');">
          </div>
          <span>Letterheads</span>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <p>Many clients opt for expensive branded (and often watermarked) paper for their letterheads. Like most Supermarkets, all paper mills and...</p>
          <a href="http://localhost/parks/letterheads" class="waves-effect waves-light btn work">
                                View Work
                            </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col xs12 m6 l4">
        <div class="flex-item">
          <div class="flexIcon" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/parks/themes/recycle/images/services/posters.png');">
          </div>
          <span>Posters</span>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <p>The standard method of printing the typical standard sized comp slip is to lay 3 or 6 up on the press...</p>
          <a href="http://localhost/parks/posters" class="waves-effect waves-light btn work">
                                View Work
                            </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col xs12 m6 l4">
        <div class="flex-item">
          <div class="flexIcon" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/parks/themes/recycle/images/services/stationery-bundles.png');">
          </div>
          <span>Stationery Bundles</span>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <p>We’ll do everything we can to make keep your print bill as low as possible, and that can include ‘stationery bundles’...</p>
          <a href="http://localhost/parks/stationery-bundles" class="waves-effect waves-light btn work">
                                View Work
                            </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<span id="calculatewidth" style="font-size:25px;font-weight:500;text-transform: uppercase;display:none;"></span>
```